# Unable to insert cells in UITableView with data coming from API

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a situation where I have to insert cells in my `UITableView`.
I implemented these three delegate fuctions and it is working well when the data is defined in `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    categoryData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee",@"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
    _categoryMenuTable.dataSource = self;
    _categoryMenuTable.delegate = self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [categoryData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[categoryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

But in my case `categoryData` comes from an API asynchronously, that obviously loads after `viewDidLoad`.

So the real problem is, in the later case, I am unable to call the delegate methods.

PS I also tried

```
[_categoryMenuTable reloadData];
```

after setting data to `categoryData` like

```
-(void)setCategories:(NSMutableArray*)arr    {
    categoryData = arr;
    _categoryMenuTable.dataSource = self;
    _categoryMenuTable.delegate = self;
    [_categoryMenuTable reloadData];
}
```

I more thing i want to mention is I am using MMDawerController
https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

How can I get the data from the API into my table?

Comment: How do you parse data from server?

Comment: i parsed it and stored it in a NSMutableArray *arr

Comment: Can you show how are you doing this, i.e. data parsing.

Comment: plz share the code how u r parsing and storing in arr

Comment: that is not the issue, i am sure about it because in function setCategories, even if i set values for categoryData manualy then also it is not working.

Comment: are you sure that you are calling setCategories function after parsing the data?

Comment: yes because i logged the data inside setCategories method.

Comment: Your code seems ok 
debug your whole code stepwise Print your array in console 
I am sure you will track the issue and solve it
there is some minor error

Comment: where r u calling setCategoiries ?

Comment: please check my comment on shpasta's answer.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri do you have some clue?? I am still stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many Hurdles Solving the issue, but finally get through it. Let me explain the issues and solution one by one.

Issue 1: 
Initially I was unable to call function of different controller, but after some time I was able to call it like this.

```
ClassName* cm = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifierName"];
[cm functionName : argumentName];
```

Issue 2:
Now I am able to call functions and also can send data, but still unable to trigger delegate methods of UITableView after some searching, I got to know that I have to reload data to trigger delegate methods like this.

```
[UITableViewObject reloadData];
```

Issue 3:
Delegate Methods still aren't called so I go with the viewDidAppear method and now I was able to call delegate methods. But unable to provide data from API to viewDidAppear. So I created a global class and set the data coming from API (in class A) to it and again get data (in Class B) from this global class and everything is working fine.

I am mentioning the code used it might helpful to someone.

```
//default.m (data load in this class from API)

GlobalData *obj = [GlobalData getInstance];
// categoryDataFromApi is of type NSMutableArray and set it to a property of global class
obj. categoryData = categoryDataFromApi;



// category.m (UITableView exist in this class and all the delegate methods also exist in this class)
// reloading data in viewDidAppear to trigger delegate methods.

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    GlobalData *obj = [GlobalData getInstance];
    categoryData = obj.categoryData;
    [_categoryMenuTable reloadData];
}



// Global.h 

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface GlobalData 
    @property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *categoryData;
    +(GlobalData*)getInstance;
@end


// Global.m

#import "GlobalData.h"
@implementation GlobalData
    static GlobalData *instance = nil;
    +(GlobalData *)getInstance{
         @synchronized(self){
             if(instance == nil)
                 instance = [GlobalData new];
         }
         return instance;
     }
 @end
```

Please let me know if there is some better solution exist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `reloadData` instead of `reload` to call the `UITableView` delegate methods

Answer (score 0):

If your data parsing is correct (as you mentioned in comments), the reason can be that you are updating UI from background thread. UI should be updated from main thread only. Try this one when you are setting category objects and updating tableView:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self setCategories:categoriesArray];
});
```

Comment: i called setCategories method from different controller, as data get load in controller A and table view exist in controller B, so I have to call setCategories from controller A and send data to controller B's setCategory method.

Comment: You can call your setter from any place you want. I'm talking about threads. If you are updating tableView not from main thread it won't work. Put breakpoint inside `setCategories` and look at the thread number where it's called, in XCode Navigator (left panel).

Comment: This might be the issue, because I called this function after data gets load. let me check and will get back to you.

Comment: i don't get how to do this